# Maximum Amplitude

Tags: calculus

The angle $A$ of a heavily damped swinging door varies with time according to the law

$$A = \frac{\mathrm e^{-at}- \mathrm e^{-bt}}{b-a}$$

$a$ and $b$ constant. I calculated the initial (angular) position and initial angular velocity of the door at $t=0$ which is $A(0) = 0$ and $A'(0) = 1$. But calculating the greatest amplitutde at time $t_M$ is cumbersome for me?

What step I have to take. I am completely blank here. Please any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just equate the derivative to 0, find out the time and put that back in the equation?

Comment: Yes, I tried. 0 = -ae^(-at) + be^(-bt). What is the t value I should put here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{\mathrm -ae^{-at} \mathrm +be^{-bt}}{b-a} \tag{1}$$

The maximum occurs at $\displaystyle \frac{dA}{dt} = 0 \tag{2}$

$$-ae^{-at}  +be^{-bt} = 0 \tag{3}$$

$$ae^{-at} = be^{-bt} \tag{4}$$

$$e^{(b-a)t} = \frac{b}{a}\tag{5}$$

$$t = \frac{ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{b-a} \tag{6} $$

Comment: Wow, I was correct till step 4 but after that, I made a little mistake.

Comment: So did Andrew Wiles.

Comment: Thank you, arthur. Sometimes I didn't confident in my answer or maybe I am weak in algebra and adjusting expression.